# String from android activity to string in html inside assets folder

Tags: android, html, android-assets

I Have an application with an html file inside of the assets folder. I want it so that when the user clicks a button, inside of the Android applications activity, the contents of the button get put into a string and passes the string to a string inside of the html file. Taking the contents of the button and passing them to a string inside of the activity I can do. I want to know how can I take the string, that I got from the button, and pass the information to the html file inside of my assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to display the HTML file with different data based on a button push?  You can use %s or %d in your HTML file as well as $1..$n to do multiple replacements:

You have $1%d new $2%s.

Pseudo-Code

getHtmlFromAssets(myfile.html, unReadThings, things) where unReadThings is a number and things is a string.

Make sense?

Conceptually (though you'll be using HTML): http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-format-strings/

Or less Android specific: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html

Comment: I am actually calling a string from one website into the application. What I want to do with the string is display it in the html file.

Comment: Then what I propose should still work.  You're just performing a string replacement based on it's position for replacement $1..$n and it's type %d (number) or %s (string).  And, honestly, you could bypass the built in Android stuff and devise your own.  $FIRST_NAME$ then do a simple string substitution for $FIRST_NAME$ or $WHATEVER_YOU_WANT$ and $AS$ $MANY$ $AS$ $YOU$ $WANT$ to replace.  Lots of messaging apps allow you to do that to substitute names into the text messages being sent.

Comment: Could I get an example possibly? I sort of see where you are going with this but I am honestly not sure how to do this. I am fairly new to html and PHP stuff.

Comment: or direct me to a site that has an example. I am having a bit of a hard time looking for an example

Answer (score 0):

Resources (including Assets) are meant to be read. You can open a `raw` file, call a `anim` file, get a string from `String` xml file. However, you can't *write* to a resource.

As [AssetsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) documentation states:

> This class presents a lower-level API that allows you to **open and read raw files** that have been bundled with the application as a simple stream of bytes.

Now, what to do? I suggest you look into [other types of Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). For your case, I *strongly* suggest [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: How about if I use something like a HTMLPost and post the data to the html file?

Comment: You mean to the html file in the assets? You can't.

Answer (score 0):

addJavaScriptInterface method helps us pass values from a webpage to your android XML view or vice-versa. You can invoke your activity class method form your webpage
On create:

```
 WebView Wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    Wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
    = new JavaScriptInterface(this);         
    Wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Wv.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    Wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

then create a class myJavaScriptInterface

```
    class JavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;
int tpressure;
JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
   tpressure=0;
}

public int Pressure(){  
    return tpressure++;
}
```

}

Sample html file would be:

```
     <head>
            <title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
         setInterval(function() {
         $("#tire1").html(AndroidFunction.Pressure())  
          }, 2000);
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>        
    <div id="some">
     Tire Pressure:
</div>
    <div id="tire1">
     0
</div>

</body>
```